# Why external CSS file doesn't work when I use semantic-ui?

Tags: html, css, semantic-ui

I'd like to use external CSS file but it doesn't work.

I want to change text color of menu to red. (Look at home.html. I want to change color of the text 'intro', 'picture', 'support')
I tried this by write external css file. But it didn't work.
I think class 'item' is also used in semantic-ui, so the 'item' code in external css file doesn't apply because of overlapping.
And then, How can I change text color with using semantic-ui tag simultaneously?

My home.html file and common.css file below.

home.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>title1111</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/common.css" type="text/css" >
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/home.css" type="text/css" >
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.4.1/semantic.css">


</head>


<body>


    <div class="ui secondary  menu">
        <a class="item">intro</a>
        <a class="item">picture</a>
        <a class="item">support</a>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="body">


    </div>
    <div id="footer">

    </div>




    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.4.1/semantic.min.js"></script>
</body>
```

common.css

```
.item{
    color: red;

}
```

p.s answer without using '!important' would be welcomed!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Step 1

Change the order of your imports. When you import the Semantic-Ui stylesheet after your other stylesheets it overrides your rules.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.4.1/semantic.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/home.css" type="text/css" >
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/common.css" type="text/css" >
```

#### Step 2

Be more specific in your rules, include the hierarchy.

```css
.ui.menu .item {
    color: red;
}
```